# Setting up QA environment on Vagrant Ubuntu Wily 64 using capybara

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, rspec, vagrant, capybara

I am attempting to set up a QA environment with capybara on a Vagrant VM using the wily/64 box. I have followed the following link with no success:

[Installing Selenium on a Ubuntu VM with Vagrant](http://www.lukemerrett.com/2014/01/28/installing-selenium-on-a-ubuntu-vm-with-vagrant/).

The article uses a 32 bit box, so I have modified the commands to use the 64 bit chrome driver.

Everything seems to work fine untill I attempt to start google-chrome with the command 
`google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 &`

I get the error `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":10".`

Searching other SO articles led me to a post that suggested trying this command: `Xvfb :21 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -extension RANDR &`

After running this command I run `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 &` again which gives me the following output:

`Created new window in existing browser session.` But it just hangs there without allowing me to put anymore input in. Can someone point me in the right direction to run capybara tests in this environment? I have also tried using headless browser testing (poltergeist) and it wasn't able to find the page.